# nginx don't log requests of a specific ip adress

Tags: nginx, ip, logging, scripting

I'm trying to don't log requests made from a specific ip address like this:

```
location = / {
    index index.php;
    if ( $remote_addr = "spe.ci.fic.ip" )
    {
        access_log off;
    }

}
```

But it doesn't work, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use correct syntax

```
location ~ ^/(css|js) {
    if ( $remote_addr = "127.0.0.1" ) 
    {
        access_log off;
    }
}
```

In your example nginx doesn't write logs only for '/' location.

Comment: I doesn't work for me :/

Comment: I tested on nginx/1.3.6, works as expected.

Comment: Initially it didn't work for me either, it works only if it matches the location.

Answer (score 4):

You can suppress specific IP's for specific logs with the `if` statement.

The following

```
map $remote_addr $log_ip {
  "192.168.0.10" 0;
  "192.168.0.11" 0;
  ~192\.168\.1\..* 0;
  default 1;
}

location /thing/ {
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access-thing.log if=$log_ip;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access-thing-json.log combined_json;
  ...
  proxy_pass http://proxy/thing/;
}
```

would not log access from IP addresses `192.168.0.10` and `192.168.0.11`, as well as the entire `192.168.1.xxx`-range, into the logfile `access-thing.log`, but it would log into the logfile `access-thing-json.log`.

Comment: This is the better answer as it avoids the (other) `if`, is more concisely flexible, and can be applied at `server` or `http` to apply to every path regardless.